# DirectX 11 - Problem with low resolution decals

Tags: shaders, directx, hlsl, projection, resolution

I'm trying to add a decal system in my DirectX engine but i'm facing some problems with the quality of the textures projected. Every other no decal texture look fine, but these ones look really bad.

What I do in the shader is:

```
    float4 PSDecal(
    in float4 iPosition : SV_Position
    ) : SV_Target
{

    int3 ss_load_coords = uint3(iPosition.xy, 0);

    float3 wPos = txWorldPos.Load(ss_load_coords).xyz;

    float4 lightSpacePos = mul(float4(wPos,1), LightViewProjection);
    lightSpacePos.xyz /= lightSpacePos.w;
    lightSpacePos.x = (lightSpacePos.x + 1) * 0.5;
    lightSpacePos.y = (1 - lightSpacePos.y) * 0.5;

    float4 light_mask = txLightMask.Sample(samLightBlackBorder, lightSpacePos.xy);
    if (lightSpacePos.w < 0)
        light_mask.xyzw = .0;

    return light_mask;
}
```

Here you can see the result decal, the original texture and the projection space of the decal:

[image]

In the last image you can see there are noticeable artifacts, and thats why the resulting image gets distorted, but I don't understand why...

Also, I have the same problem when generating the light shadows, they get pixelated too. In this case, the shadow map is being calculated correctly, and it's not distorted.

Maybe it's the world position that is being loaded?